# Azure ARM Template : Create Resource Group

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

We are new to ARM (Azure Resource Manager) templates. While working on a template, I observed that we have to supply a resource group when deploying our template. 
Is it is possible to create a resource group through a template like other resources?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now you can create a resource group using ARM templates. You can use the following template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "rgLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Southeast Asia"
    },
    "rgName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myResourceGroup"
    }
  },
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
      "name": "[parameters('rgName')]"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

You can run this using the Azure CLI. But you have to have the latest CLI version installed. I have version 2.0.43 installed. This includes **subscription level deployments** using the `az deployment` command.

To execute this run the following command.

`az deployment create --name <deployment_name> --location <resource_location> --template-file .\azuredeploy.json`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm getting the foollowing (UUID redacted)  ```{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n \"message\": \"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<UUID>/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup?api-version=2018-05-01'.\"\r\n}"}]}```

Comment: This solution is wrong and not working, it is using wrong schema, the solution bellow is right.

Comment: The `az` CLI gives a warning stating that [`deployment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_deployment_create) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. [`deployment sub create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/sub?view=azure-cli-latest#az_deployment_sub_create) should be used instead

Comment: Please note as of today, there exist different [deployment scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax) indicated by `$schema`.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution is wrong. Resource groups are deployed on the subscription level not on the resource group level. No wonder it is not working.

Note the $schema difference. it should be **subscriptionDeploymentTemplate** instead.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "string",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "location": "string",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                                
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! If you are using Azure CLI, remember to run it using `az deployment sub create`, so you will create new resource group inside your subscription.

Answer (score 5):

It is now published in the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/create-resource-group-in-template),

```
az deployment create \
  -n demoEmptyRG \
  -l southcentralus \
  --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/azure-resource-manager/emptyRG.json \
  --parameters rgName=demoRG rgLocation=northcentralus
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it is possible to create resource group through template like
>   other resources ??

For now, we can't use arm template to create Azure resource group.

Comment: Why?? any particular reason behind that.

Comment: By default, we will use Azure powershell or Azure CLI to create a new deployment with json file, here is the powershell command, like this: `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup -TemplateFile c:\Users\Desktop\jasontest2.json` , in this script, we have specify the resource group.

Comment: @BlindSniper, basically a chicken-egg situation. Resource group is created at subscription level. So `deploymentParameters.json` schema cant be used. Instead use `subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json` schema.

Answer (score -2):

the subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json schema must be used.

Comment: try including a relevant code block or steps to help out the original poster.