# Can I change github role when is connected to azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, github-actions

I'm attempting for the first time to create an ARM template using Azure and github actions. I followed all the steps to create a service principal and assign github contributor role.

I created my first template with the goal of login into azure (which worked) and creating a storage account which failed because do to an Authorization failed error. This is the warning I get:

Warning: ERROR: ***"code": "AuthorizationFailed", "message": "The client '3b1f7136-28ea-48bf-8cde-9417317fa987' with object id '3b1f7136-28ea-48bf-8cde-9417317fa987' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action' over scope '/subscriptions/***' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."***

The reason why is failing is obvious however, what is not obvious is out to fix it. The Github role is currently being assigned to a resource group; does it need to be assigned to the subscription as well? If yes, how do I assigned to subcription level?

Tried to figure how a way to assign the role to subscription

Comment: This was super helpful thank you so much. Also, is it possible to deploy resource groups using GitHub actions? Here's syntax I'm using                                                                                                      
      name: Deploy Resource Group rg-githubactions
      uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
      with:
        scope: subscription
        subscriptionId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        region: uksouth
        resourceGroupName: rg-githubActions
        template: ./arm-template/resourcegroup.json
        deploymentName: rg-githubactions

Comment: You can directly create a resource group while generating your secrets and reference it in your YML script as mentioned in this document:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-templates-command-line-github-actions/7-exercise-github-actions [Create the service principal section] and if you want to create a resource group in your ARM template itself, Refer the answers in this SO link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670797/azure-arm-template-create-resource-group

Answer (score 0):

***I deployed Azure Storage account with Service Principal and Github actions like below:-***

**My git repo:-**

[image]

> ***I used below command from this link - [Deploy Resource Manager templates by using GitHub Actions - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-github-actions?tabs=userlevel)
> to create a service principal with RBAC Contributor role assigned at
> the Subscription level :-***

**Command:-**

> az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "myML" --role contributor 
> --scopes /subscriptions/
> --sdk-auth

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Copied the json output in my Github Actions Secrets like below:-***

[image]

I used the below ARM Template to create a Storage account:-

**azuredeploy.json**

> ```
> "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
> "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",   "metadata": {
>     "_generator": {
>       "name": "bicep",
>       "version": "0.13.1.58284",
>       "templateHash": "13120038605368246703"
>     }   },   "parameters": {
>     "storageAccountType": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
>       "allowedValues": [
>         "Premium_LRS",
>         "Premium_ZRS",
>         "Standard_GRS",
>         "Standard_GZRS",
>         "Standard_LRS",
>         "Standard_RAGRS",
>         "Standard_RAGZRS",
>         "Standard_ZRS"
>       ],
>       "metadata": {
>         "description": "Storage Account type"
>       }
>     },
>     "location": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
>       "metadata": {
>         "description": "The storage account location."
>       }
>     },
>     "storageAccountName": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "defaultValue": "[format('store{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
>       "metadata": {
>         "description": "The name of the storage account"
>       }
>     }   },   "resources": [
>     {
>       "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
>       "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
>       "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
>       "location": "[parameters('location')]",
>       "sku": {
>         "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
>       },
>       "kind": "StorageV2",
>       "properties": {}
>     }   ],   "outputs": {
>     "storageAccountName": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "value": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]"
>     },
>     "storageAccountId": {
>       "type": "string",
>       "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
>     }   } }
> ```

> **Above code Reference:-**
>
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json

**My YML Script for github action :-**

***Replace the Resource group name with the existing  Resource group where you want to create your storage account in.***

**main.yml**

```yaml
on: [push]
name: Azure ARM
jobs:
    build-and-deploy:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:

        # Checkout code
      - uses: actions/checkout@main

        # Log into Azure
      - uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

        # Deploy ARM template
      - name: Deploy ARM template
        uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
        with:
          subscriptionId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION }}
          resourceGroupName: siliconrg
          template: ./azuredeploy.json
          parameters: storageAccountType=Standard_LRS

        # output containerName variable from template
      - run: echo ${{ steps.deploy.outputs.containerName }}
```

***The Github action ran successfully like below:-***

[image]

***And storage account got created in Azure Portal:-***

[image]

**References:-**

> [Exercise - Deploy ARM templates as part of your CI/CD efforts with
> GitHub Actions - Training | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-templates-command-line-github-actions/7-exercise-github-actions)